# How to insert and update two form same data into single table but different rows using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert and update two form data on single submit click to mysql table. Please help me how can I do this. Just provide me a hint.

Thank you...

Comment: Your question is too broad I believe.  If you have a specific programming question, then we can help you.

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried?

Comment: Any code example would be more than helpful.

Comment: provide a hint??

Comment: Are the two forms the SAME fields/data names? Are they two completely different forms on one page?

Comment: Hint: `insert into table (columns here) values (data set 1), (data set2);` Add code so we know what you are doing, too broad as is.

Comment: @clearshot66, there are two forms with same field name but data inserting into a single table. For ex. 1st form data inserted into a 1st row of the table and 2nd form data inserted into a 2nd row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per PHP w3Schools article about [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp) :

> The mysqli_multi_query() function performs one or more queries against
>   the database. The queries are separated with a semicolon.
>
> ```
> mysqli_multi_query(connection,query);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do field names as arrays

```
<form name='form1'>
   <input type='text' name='name[]' />  
</form>
<form name='form2'>
   <input type='text' name='name[]' />  
</form>

<?php

$connection stuff here
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query = "INSERT INTO X (val1) VALUES (?)";
for($i = 0; $i < 2 (# of inserts); $i++){

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$name[$i]);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Note that $_POST['name']; is an array if you send more than one of the same named field in using [].  print_r($_POST['name']); will show you the field values

Answer (score -1):

**On Submit Button Click :** You must call `mysql_query()` for every query.

For Example :

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1 ...";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table1 ...";
    mysql_query($sql1, $con);
    mysql_query($sql2, $con);
}
```

---

**Important**

`mysql_query()` is deprecated! Please use `mysqli_query()` http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

You can also use `mysqli_multi_query()` http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 ...; INSERT INTO donatie ...;";
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Not my Dv but why suggest `mysql_*` from the start?

Comment: @LuFFy, I have to insert data into single table not in two tables

Comment: OP's question is really vague, so it is difficult to figure out exactly what is needed. Though, i think this is the right path. But please use MYSQLI or PDO

Comment: @LuFFy update your entire answer and talk only about `mysqli_*` or `PDO` though this question does not deserve an answer